# How do I join my own crew in GTA 5 Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I created my own crew recently, but it doesn't show up when I get on GTA online. How do I join my own crew on PS3?

Answer (score 3):

You have to join the crew through the [Rockstar Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/).  If you haven't done so, create an account and link it to your PS3 gamer profile.  This should add GTA V as a game in your social club profile.

You'll get a GTA V career page to navigate to once you've done that.  There it shows all three of the single player characters and your online character.  If you click on your online character just below the thumbnail image of that character you'll see their current cash and a big "Join a Crew" button.

Answer (score 2):

There's going to be a problem if your NAT type is set to 3.  You created your own crew, maybe no one joined?  And if you *do* have members you'll see them in the pause menu under:

> menu > online > crews > my crew

If you have members in your crew, press join game and you'll head straight there to join them.